# Firefox support for Script# and Implementation of Generics

Tags: c#, .net, script#

I've used [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) for a while and have had problems getting projects to work out of the box with Fireox. I had to change a couple of lines in the `sscorlib.js` files.

Will Script# be cross-browser compatible in the future?  Will it use generics in a future release?

Answer (score 3):

Dworrad,

Are you using the compat layer (sscompat.js) that helps in cross-browser scenarios (Firefox/Safari)?

I'd love to hear the specific problems you've run into and had to fix, so they can be verified/addressed.

As for generics, that is on the roadmap, but can't yet say when exactly they would be supported. I would have thought that rather than using literals (assuming Script.Literal), you'd be using Object, and non-strongly typed collections and casting to the right type.